# How to detect the maintenance window will be closed event in Doze mode?

Tags: android, android-doze-and-standby, android-workmanager

I want to start a hard `Worker.class`, but when phone switching to Doze mode and then maintenance window comes sometimes is not enough time to finish Job and I need an event to close timers and to save databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 10 mins to complete your work. If you need more time, I suggest splitting up your work and scheduling more `Worker`s.

Comment: My understanding of this response is that this 10 minute limit reflects to time constraint of the Worker's doWork(), correct? You're not necessarily saying that Doze mode maintenance windows are 10 minutes long, right?